# Set Flash Memory Location to certain values on MSP430 using GCC

Tags: gcc, msp430, mspgcc

How do you set a few bytes of *flash* to be programmed by the flash programmer during programming of the mcu to be a certain value using msp GCC toolchain?  For example, TI C/C++ compiler toolchain, includes assembler, and the following lines of assembly set the memory locations to the desired values:

```
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
 .sect ".BSLSIG"
 .retain
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
                 .word       0xFFFF         ; 0x17F0
BslProtectVecLoc .word       BSL_Protect    ; 0x17F2 adress of function
PBSLSigLoc       .word       03CA5h         ; 0x17F4 1st BSL signature
SBSLSigLoc       .word       0C35Ah         ; 0x17F6 2nd BSL signature
                 .word       0xFFFF         ; 0x17F8
BslEntryLoc      .word       BSL_Entry_JMP  ; 0x17FA BSL_Entry_JMP
```

Is there a way to do something similar using msp GCC toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

The GNU assembler has the same mechanisms.
For example, here is how the [MSP430 startup code](http://www.sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=libgloss/msp430/crt0.S;hb=HEAD) puts the address of the startup code into the reset vector:

```
        .section ".resetvec", "a"
__msp430_resetvec_hook:
        .word   __crt0_start
```

As with the TI compiler, this requires the section (here: `.resetvec`) to be defined in the [linker script](http://www.sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=libgloss/msp430/intr_vectors.ld;hb=HEAD).

Comment: I think it's not necessary to change the linker script, at it's possible to set the start address of a section in linker parameters: `LDFLAGS += "-Wl,--section-start=.resetvec=0x5000"`. And section attributes can be set in GNU C using the  `__attribute__ ((section (".resetvec")))` syntax.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing, but use GCC C compiler?

Comment: @kfx How can you set section *attributes* in C?

Comment: @user1135541 See kfx's comment.

Comment: May be able to do this `const uint16_t __attrib__(__attribute__((section(".BSLSigLoc"), used)) SigLocVar = 0xC35A3CA5;`  but I am not 100% sure yet